# React Native 0.51.0 Fetch HTTPS network request failed

Tags: ios, react-native, fetch, react-native-ios

I am currently facing an error Network Request failed.

This is my code :

```
fetch("https://nextbus.comfortdelgro.com.sg/eventservice.svc/BusStops")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJSON) => {
    console.log("JSON",responseJSON)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

I am building an iOS App, I have edited the **info.plist** file

```
<key>nextbus.comfortdelgro.com.sg/eventservice.svc/BusStops</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
```

My URL is HTTPS, so i don't understand why am i facing this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue couldn't figure it out. I started using Axios Library for making requests. By using Axios you can cut out the middle step of passing the result of http request to the JSON method. Axios just returns the data object you would expect

Comment: Using Axios doesn't solve the problem, I'm facing. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. To prove that to yourself just swap the url to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1` and it will work perfectly.

The issue seems to be caused by an encoding issue with the response.
When I enter the url into the JSON formatter at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ it gives the following response -
`Invalid encoding, expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.`

I don't know enough about the character sets to suggest a fix for this, but hopefully that helps with where to start looking!

Comment: Hi, the JSON is valid, I just checked. Maybe you copied wrongly.